# Python copy contents of a file into another at a different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, parsing, copy

I am trying to copy contents of a file into another located at a different directory.
I am trying it by 2 methods -

```
shutil.copy('abc.txt', '/projects/fldr/notes/work/sg1234/lib/test/main/xyz.txt')
```

Problem with this method is that there are different users, so I can't use sg1234 in path, I couldn't think of a way to change user so path becomes -

```
shutil.copy('abc.txt', '/projects/fldr/notes/work/{user}/lib/test/main/xyz.txt')
```

and if I am trying to do it like this then it is throwing an error.-

```
shutil.copy('abc.txt', '/../../../../../../../../xyz.txt')
```

I also tried -

```
file.open(output_file_path + 'xyz.txt')
shutil.copy('abc.txt', 'xyz.txt')
```

But in this case it is only creating an empty file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know the usernames? Is it a matter of inserting them in the path?

Comment: If you have the username in variable `user` then the syntax to insert the username is `f'/projects/fldr/notes/work/{user}/lib/test/main/xyz.txt'` (note the initial `f`).

Comment: Regarding your `/../../` etc, it's not clear exactly what you are attempting here, but note that because the path starts with `/` it is still an absolute path (and `..` in the system root directory points back to the system root directory).

Comment: @zmike I don't know the usernames, the users will open the file in there area, I am looking for something so it should automatically add there name to path, or if there is a method which doesn't require to enter file path, that would do too.

Comment: you can use the absolute path, no?

Comment: @dio, I tried that, but it isn't creating a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import shutil
import getuser

user = getpass.getuser()

shutil.copy('abc.txt', f'/projects/fldr/notes/work/{user}/lib/test/main/xyz.txt')
```

Comment: I don't know the usernames, the users will open the file in there area, I am looking for something so it should automatically add there name to path, or if there is a method which doesn't require to enter file path, that would do too.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should set an absolute path for your source file `abc.txt` to avoid problem. Is the user running this script?